# Canceling running coroutineWorker doesn't fire failure in a certain pattern

Tags: android, coroutine, android-workmanager

I'm trying stopping running coroutineWorker from notification button. I tried 3 methods and 2 of them calls "Result.failure()" & working fine. However another one doesn't.

Below CoroutineWorker shows foregroundInfo and Starts ringtone.

```
class RingWork(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    
    companion object {
        val ALARM_CHANNEL_ID = "alarm_channel6"
    }

    lateinit var ringtoneSound: Ringtone

    val context = applicationContext
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {


        return try {

            val alarmId = inputData.getInt("alarmId", 0)

            val notificationMgr =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            //CHANNEL
            val alarmChannel = NotificationChannel(
                ALARM_CHANNEL_ID, "alarm" ,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            alarmChannel.setSound(null, null)
            alarmChannel.enableVibration(false)
            alarmChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            notificationMgr.createNotificationChannel(alarmChannel)



            val fullScreenIntent = Intent(context, LockscreenActivity::class.java).putExtra("alarmId", alarmId)
            //This calls "failure" properly 
            val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, fullScreenIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            //This calls "failure" properly 
            val stop1PendingIntent =
                WorkManager.getInstance(context).createCancelPendingIntent(getId())


            val s2Intent = Intent(context, StopAlarmReceiver::class.java).putExtra("alarmId", alarmId)
            //This is not.
            val stop2PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, s2Intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)


           
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ALARM_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(null)
                .setVibrate(null)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_name, "Stop1", stop1PendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_name, "Stop2", stop2PendingIntent)

            setForeground(
                ForegroundInfo(1999999, builder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)
            )


            ringtoneSound =
                RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))


            ringtoneSound.play()


            delay(30000L)
            ringtoneSound.stop()


            Result.success()

        } catch (e: Exception) {

            Result.failure()

        } finally {

            cleanup()
        }


    }


   fun cleanup(){

       ringtoneSound.stop()
   }
}
```

In LockScreenActivity, there is a button to stop ringtone.

```
binding.stoppingbutton.setOnClickListener {
   val workMgr = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
   workMgr.cancelUniqueWork("RingWork-$alarmId")
   finish()
}
```

This calls "result.failure" and "finally" then ringtone will stop, notification will disapear. working fine.

However, if I press "Stop2" button on the notification.

```
class StopAlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val alarmId = intent.getIntExtra("alarmId", 0)
        val workMgr = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        workMgr.cancelUniqueWork("RingWork-$alarmId")
    }
}
```

It cancels worker, but it won't call "result.failure" and "finally", so ringtone won't stop. Notification also won't disappear.

fullScreenPendingIntent and stop2PendingIntent are doing the same thing, but why it won't behave same?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your **PendingIntent** like this and it will trigger onReceive:

```
val stop2PendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, downloadFile.productId, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        else
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, downloadFile.productId, cancelIntent, 0)
```